# With SQlite, how do you show current PRAGMA settings?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

With SQlite, how do you show current PRAGMA settings?

And when setting them, are they persistent, or do they need to be set with every query?

Chris

Answer (score 11):

In the simplest form, current pragma settings can be obtained by simply executing an sql statement with the syntax `PRAGMA <command>`. For example, when debugging in PHP using PDO, you could do something like this:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite: myDb.sqlite");
$synchronous = $db->query("PRAGMA synchronous")->fetchColumn();
```

To set the values, use `PRAGMA <command> = <value>`.  There will be no return value, however (so don't bother with `fetch`ing anything).

```
$db->query("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF");
```

As to the second question of whether the commands are persistent, as turlando said, there is no general answer as it is depends on which PRAGMA statement is being issued.  Just check [the sqlite pragma docs](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) to be sure.  And if you are uncertain, simply use the above code to check whether your settings have persisted.

Comment: If you want to know **if foreign keys are on, the query is `PRAGMA foreign_keys`**
JavaScript/JS/loose TypeScript/TS version  https://jsfiddle.net/7qvpchg2/ , I know this is offtopic, but I found this answer while looking for JS solution, getting is shown both no-transaction and through transcation